# How to unit test a class which calls service bus queue client SendAsync method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a interface which has a method to create instance of queue client and message factory. I have created a concrete implementation of the same and now i am trying to unit test the functionality which is used for send message to queue. I have written below code for the same:

```
private readonly Mock<IQueueClientProvider> queueClientProvider;

private readonly Mock<IJsonSerializer> jsonSerializer;

private readonly Mock<ILogger<QueueConnector>> logger;

private readonly ModelLogger<QueueConnector> modelLogger;

private readonly QueueConnector queueConnector;

private readonly Mock<QueueClient> queueClient;

public QueueConnectorTests() 

{

   queueClientProvider = new Mock< IQueueClientProvider >();

   queueClient = new Mock< QueueClient >();

   logger = new Mock< ILogger< QueueConnector >>();

   jsonSerializer = new Mock< IJsonSerializer >();

   modelLogger = new ModelLogger<QueueConnector>(logger.Object,     jsonSerializer.Object);

queueConnector = new QueueConnector(modelLogger, queueClientProvider.Object);

}

[Fact]
public async void ShouldBeAbleToSendMessage()

{

  BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage();

brokeredMessage.CorrelationId = "0HKVUFCD6Q5JL";

queueClientProvider.Setup(q =>q.CreateQueueClient()).Returns(queueClient.Object);

// Act

await queueConnector.SendMessage(brokeredMessage);

// Assert

 queueClient.Verify(q => q.SendAsync(brokeredMessage));


}
```

but getting exception

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Parent does not have a default constructor.
>   The default constructor must be explicitly defined.

Can someone please help me with this not sure whats going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a type with an internal constructor using Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279412/mocking-a-type-with-an-internal-constructor-using-moq)

Comment: we would need more details: which line is throwing the exception ? Also, could you post the code of QueueConnector's constructor and SendMessage method ?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I had to restructure my code, sendAsync method was expecting a brokered message which could not be mocked so I created my own implement ion of the same if I remember correctly. It's been a while when I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the `IQueueClient` interface inside your code instead of the QueueClient implementation. The `SendAsync` method is part of the `ISenderClient` interface which `IQueueClient` inherits from.

Once you've used `IQueueClient`, you can do something like this:

```
var queueClientMock = new Mock<IQueueClient>();
queueClientMock.Setup(x => 
x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Message>))).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but question I posted is very old and at that time we didn't have that Interface.

Comment: True, but people still visit this thread today. So an answer is helpful.